# JQuery animated vertical menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a vertical menu which includes some animation.

I would like the user to hover over part of the the element which triggers the element to expand in width and show some text.

I have had a go at it for the past couple of days but feel i am now just making things worse!

Any help or advice on this would be much appreciated.

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danieljoseph/NZ2QL/3/

Here is the JQuery:

```
$("nav li").hover(function () {
  $("nav li").css('width', 'auto');
});

$("#about-btn").mouseover(function () {
  $("#about-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "190px"
}, 1000);
});
$("#about-btn").mouseout(function () {
  $("#about-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "0"
  }, 1000);
});

$("#services-btn").mouseover(function () {
  $("#services-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "190px"
  }, 1000);
});
$("#services-btn").mouseout(function () {
  $("#services-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "0"
  }, 1000);
});

$("#work-btn").mouseover(function () {
  $("#work-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "190px"
  }, 1000);
});
$("#work-btn").mouseout(function () {
  $("#work-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "0"
  }, 1000);
});

$("#contact-btn").mouseover(function () {
  $("#contact-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "190px"
  }, 1000);
});
$("#contact-btn").mouseout(function () {
  $("#contact-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "0"
  }, 1000);
});
```

I'm an amateur when it comes to `JQuery` so any tips and explanations would be great if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/NZ2QL/8/ just a quick fix, your code should be improved more, such as by using the shorthand method `hover` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[`Demo Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2QL/34/)*

*jQuery Code*

```
$("nav li").hover(function () {
    console.log($(this).children().children('.tab'));
    $(".tab", this).stop().animate({
        width: "190px"
    }, 1000);
}, function () {
    $(".tab", this).stop().animate({
        width: "0"
    }, 1000);
});
```

According to me direct children of `<ul>` must be only `<li>` so I even changed there position which was wrong in the fiddle you gave...

*NOTE: This task could be done using pure css, which would be much lighter*

---

*Update Not part of the question:*

### *[`The same above feature using plain css`](http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2QL/38/)*

Comment: Thanks very much for providing a CSS option. I would ideally like to use the CSS version as it is light but how would i go about doing this without the 'margin-right / extra hover' the text is causing in the .tab element?

Comment: @user2965596 I did not understood your above question... But did edited the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2QL/77/

Comment: How would i get rid of the black space in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danieljoseph/NZ2QL/79/

I tried making the width 60px on the nav ul element but this makes the .tab element go beneath the first span element.

Not really sure how else to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you really need:

http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2QL/25/

```js
$(".menuItem").mouseover(function () {
    var tab = $('.tab[data-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]').first();
    tab.stop().animate({
        width: "190px"
    }, 1000);
});
$(".menuItem").mouseout(function () {
    var tab = $('.tab[data-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]').first();
    tab.stop().animate({
        width: "0px"
    }, 1000);
});
```

An interesting article that may help:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup/

Cheers ;)

Comment: That's a lot closer than what I had, but mouseover still triggers on the element below when another element is open above it when your'e not hovering directly over the letter...

Comment: I think the key thing here is that the entire anchor element needs to be resized, not just the span inside of it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. You don't need to hover directly over the letter. Moreover you can now bind it to anything you want. And trigger on any desired element that has a specified id.

--edit
You can now separate things and so on.. and fiddle around with element display properties.

That's just a concept so you can move on with it.

Comment: My point is that the anchor element should be resized when you mouseout and mouseover.  In your example when you mouse out of one and go directly below it expands despite you not having moused over the letter.  From the beginning, only mouseover on the letter triggers the event.  Maybe this is the desired behavior, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Minus the animations being a little off, this is what I was trying to explain: http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2QL/75.  Previous animations still need to be stopped correctly and i should reclass the items as you did, but...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2QL/76/.  There, (minus code cleanup/improving jquery selectors as I don't have time for that right now...)

Comment: Thanks for everyones input. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What i'd recommend is placing the mouseout events on the .tab classes, and you should get what you want.  I'll update your fiddle in a second to show you what i mean.

```
$("nav li").hover(function () {
  $("nav li").css('width', 'auto');
});

$("#about-btn").mouseover(function () {
  $("#about-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "190px"
}, 1000);
});
$("#about-btn .tab").mouseout(function () {
  $("#about-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "0"
  }, 1000);
});

$("#services-btn").mouseover(function () {
  $("#services-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "190px"
  }, 1000);
});
$("#services-btn .tab").mouseout(function () {
  $("#services-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "0"
  }, 1000);
});

$("#work-btn").mouseover(function () {
  $("#work-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "190px"
  }, 1000);
});
$("#work-btn .tab").mouseout(function () {
  $("#work-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "0"
  }, 1000);
});

$("#contact-btn").mouseover(function () {
  $("#contact-btn .tab").animate({
    width: "190px"
  }, 1000);



$("#contact-btn .tab").mouseout(function () {
      $("#contact-btn .tab").animate({
        width: "0"
      }, 1000);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2QL/11/

This is a little closer, but still needs some fixing.

That should be what you need.  It could be cleaned up a little more to condense the code, but the functionality is what you want, I'm pretty sure.
http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2QL/76/

MY FINAL EDIT:

```
$(".menuItem li").hover(
function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"width":"250px"}, {queue:false, duration:1000});
    $(this).children(".tab").animate({"width":"190px"}, {queue: false, duration:1000})},
function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({"width":"60px"}, {queue:false, duration:1000});
    $(this).children(".tab").animate({"width":"0px"}, {queue: false, duration:1000})}
);
```

Modified HTML and css are here:
http://jsfiddle.net/NZ2QL/81/